# Browser renders webpage differently on refresh (when nothing has changed)

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

When I refresh my webpage, the browser (Chrome) renders it differently each time. I have done nothing in between pressing refresh.

Page can be seen here: http://www.melbournedodgeball.com.au/dodgeballnew/team.php?teamid=5

If you click refresh a few times it occasionally renders the page wrong. Why is this happenening and how can I stop it?

Here are some screenshots of what I mean if you don't get a similar result:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1859080/Screen%20shot%202011-05-10%20at%206.33.40%20PM.png

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1859080/Screen%20shot%202011-05-10%20at%206.34.01%20PM.png

EDIT: Thanks for the help guys, it seems to have stopped happening after I set the image to float to the left and then set the containing div to overflow: hidden.

Comment: can't reproduce in Chrome 11.

Comment: user730952: Please disable any extensions you might be using. In my experience they can induce the behaviour you're describing. You can check by clicking CTRL+SHIFT+N to open a new incognito window and test your page there.

Comment: Strangest thing... I saw the same behavior on your site two minutes ago, but now it's gone...

Answer (score 2):

For me it always renders "wrong". You need to put #achievements before #teamlogo in your HTML, or use relative positioning to push it back up.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably the caching of your browser.
Try with firefox and hit ctrl+R+shift.

Or restart chrome completely and see if the problem still occurs

and you did not close a tag correctly :

```
<ul class="subnav">
                        <li><a href="season.php?season=3">Sundays</a></li>
                        <li><a href="hall-of-fame.php">Hall of Fame</a></li>
                    </ul
```

Comment: it was switching back and forth between the two renderings every few times i clicked refresh so i don't think it is the cache otherwise it should've stayed with one.
ahh i saw the validator point out that warning, but where exactly do I need to close it? i might be blind...!

Answer (score 1):

If the page is being generated dynamically, then there could be a problem with the script. Even if you have done nothing, there can be things going on at the server between refreshes. Potentially, each refresh is displaying a *different* page.

Comment: @Thomas That would explain it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting... 
A couple solutions I can think of would be to set a defined width and height to the content's wrapper. I see that the unaligned content is floating, sometimes this can be fixed by giving your wrapper set dimension between different browsers.

If your content is being loaded dynamically, the it is possible that you're appending it in a way that doesn't render properly between different browsers -- perhaps the combination of your layout and appendature of dynamic content could have reached that browser-specific mismatch.

PS -- great UI :)

Edit: By seeing another users response, I'd go with that -- you have an unclosed tag. (@Paolo_NL_FR)

Comment: @Atticus you're not answering the question, at least not fully. You're guessing and asking another question. You should comment on the original question.

Comment: Actually I've taken a look in a couple browsers, examined the source, and am offering 2 suggestive fixes that may give a solution -- adjust the way it's being appended if dynamic, and if static then fix the wrapper. How is this not an answer?

Comment: @Atticus simply the fact that here are 2 question marks in your answer makes people more condoned towards downvoting. Talk with more definity, e.g, "Try setting a fixed width and height to the wrapper. If your content is defined dynamically, check how it's added and see if it conflicts with your layout"

Comment: @Thomas Right.. either of which point towards the same suggested solution... Clearly homeschooling worked out for you Tom.

Comment: @Atticus ;-) if you edit your answer, i'll remove my downvote. :D

Comment: thanks, would you be able to point out where the unclosed tag is? i can't quite spot it

Comment: It's in your navigation -- seasion -> hall of fame -> there's a closing </ul> that doesn't have the **>** at the end of it.. it's written as </ul